# Yii2: kartik GridView - filter not working if field from 1:n relation is displayed

Tags: gridview, yii2, relational-database, yii2-model, yii2-grid

I have a gridview for a model, displaying an attribute `gender` and and a field `lang_code` from 1:n relation `language`.

When I filter for 'female' it displays the 310 females (out of the 600 total entries). If I then clear the filter, 0 entries are showed (instead of all 600).

When I remove `lang_code` from the view, the filter resets correctly when cleared.

This is how I query for the 1:n relation in my modelSearch.php:

```
        public $languages;

        public function rules()
        {
            return [

                    [[ ...,'languages',...], 'safe'],
                   ];
         }

        public function search($params)
        {
           $query = Sprecher::find();
           $query = $query->distinct()->joinWith(['languages', ...]);

           $dataProvider->sort->attributes['languages'] = [

                'asc' => ['language.lang_code' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['language.lang_code' => SORT_DESC],
            ];
         ...
         $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'language.lang_code', $this->languages])
         ...
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

full ModelSearch:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Sprecher;

/**
 * SprecherSearch represents the model behind the search form of `app\models\Sprecher`.
 */
class SprecherSearch extends Sprecher
{

    public $languages;
    public $dialekte;
    public $einsatzbereiche;
    public $nationalitaeten;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {




        return [
            [['id', 'hat_erfahrung_synchron', 'ist_schauspieler', 'ist_ahv_pflichtig', 'braucht_neue_samples'], 'integer'],
            [[ 'einsatzbereiche','dialekte','languages','nationalitaeten','vorname', 'nachname', 'gender', 'stimmalter', 'stimmlage', 'stimmcharakter', 'mitglied_verein', 'bemerkungen', 'web', 'studio', 'skype', 'geburtsdatum', 'ahv_nummer'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Sprecher::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $query = $query->distinct()->joinWith(['languages', 'dialekte', 'einsatzbereiche', 'nationalitaeten']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['languages'] = [
            // The tables are the ones our relation are configured to
            // in my case they are prefixed with "tbl_"
            'asc' => ['language.lang_code' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['language.lang_code' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['dialekte'] = [
            // The tables are the ones our relation are configured to
            // in my case they are prefixed with "tbl_"
            'asc' => ['dialekt.lang_code' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['dialekt.lang_code' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['einsatzbereiche'] = [
            // The tables are the ones our relation are configured to
            // in my case they are prefixed with "tbl_"
            'asc' => ['einsatzbereich.bereich' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['einsatzbereich.bereich' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['nationalitaeten'] = [
            // The tables are the ones our relation are configured to
            // in my case they are prefixed with "tbl_"
            'asc' => ['nationalitaet.code' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['nationalitaet.code' => SORT_DESC],
        ];



        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'hat_erfahrung_synchron' => $this->hat_erfahrung_synchron,
            'ist_schauspieler' => $this->ist_schauspieler,
            'geburtsdatum' => $this->geburtsdatum,
            'ist_ahv_pflichtig' => $this->ist_ahv_pflichtig,
            'braucht_neue_samples' => $this->braucht_neue_samples

        ]);




        $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'gender', $this->gender]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'stimmalter', $this->stimmalter]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'stimmlage', $this->stimmlage]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'stimmcharakter', $this->stimmcharakter]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'vorname', $this->vorname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'nachname', $this->nachname])


            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'mitglied_verein', $this->mitglied_verein])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'bemerkungen', $this->bemerkungen])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'web', $this->web])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'studio', $this->studio])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'skype', $this->skype])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ahv_nummer', $this->ahv_nummer])
            ->andFilterWhere(['in', 'language.lang_code', $this->languages])
            ->andFilterWhere(['in', 'dialekt.lang_code', $this->dialekte])
            ->andFilterWhere(['in', 'nationalitaet.code', $this->nationalitaeten])
            ->andFilterWhere(['in', 'einsatzbereich.bereich', $this->einsatzbereiche]);




        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

full Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "sprecher".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $vorname
 * @property string $nachname
 * @property string $gender
 * @property string $nationalitaet
 * @property string $stimmalter
 * @property string $stimmlage
 * @property string $stimmcharakter
 * @property int $hat_erfahrung_synchron
 * @property int $ist_schauspieler
 * @property string $mitglied_verein
 * @property string $bemerkungen
 * @property string $web
 * @property string $studio
 * @property string $skype
 * @property string $geburtsdatum
 * @property string $ahv_nummer
 * @property int $ist_ahv_pflichtig
 * @property string $sprecher_id
 * @property string $korrespondenz_lang_code
 * @property string $tel
 * @property string $tel2
 * @property string $tel3
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $strasse
 * @property string $plz_org
 * @property string $firma
 * @property string $bank
 * @property int $ist_vps_mitglied
 * @property int $braucht_neue_samples
 *
 * @property Sample[] $samples
 * @property Dialekt[] $dialekte
 * @property language[] $languages
 * @property Einsatzbereich[] $einsatzbereiche
 * @property Nationalitaet[] $nationalitaeten
 */
class Sprecher extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public $gender_search;

    /**
     * @var UploadedFile[]
     */
    public $imageFiles;

    public $selected = false;

    private function getSelected() {
        return $this->selected;
    }

    private static $auswahl_liste_id;

    public static function getAuswahl_liste_id()
    {
        return SPRECHER::$auswahl_liste_id;
    }

    public static function setAuswahl_liste_id($id)
    {
        Sprecher::$auswahl_liste_id = $id;
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'sprecher';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['vorname', 'nachname', 'hat_erfahrung_synchron', 'ist_schauspieler', 'braucht_neue_samples'], 'required'],
            [['hat_erfahrung_synchron', 'ist_schauspieler', 'ist_vps_mitglied', 'ist_ahv_pflichtig', 'braucht_neue_samples'], 'integer'],
            [['geburtsdatum'], 'safe'],
            [['vorname', 'nachname', 'studio', 'skype'], 'string', 'max' => 64],
            [['gender'], 'string', 'max' => 12],
            [['stimmalter'], 'string', 'max' => 7],
            [['stimmlage', 'stimmcharakter', 'mitglied_verein', 'ahv_nummer'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['bemerkungen', 'web'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['sprecher_id'], 'string', 'max' => 4],
            [['korrespondenz_lang_code', 'tel', 'email', 'strasse', 'plz_org', 'firma', 'bank', 'tel2', 'tel3'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'System ID',
            'vorname' => 'Vorname',
            'nachname' => 'Nachname',
            'gender' => 'Gender',
            'stimmalter' => 'Stimmalter',
            'stimmlage' => 'Stimmlage',
            'stimmcharakter' => 'Stimmcharakter',
            'hat_erfahrung_synchron' => 'hat Synchron-Erfahrung',
            'ist_schauspieler' => 'Ist Schauspieler',
            'mitglied_verein' => 'Mitglied Verein',
            'bemerkungen' => 'Bemerkungen',
            'web' => 'Web',
            'studio' => 'Studio',
            'skype' => 'Skype',
            'geburtsdatum' => 'Geburtsdatum',
            'ahv_nummer' => 'Ahv Nummer',
            'ist_ahv_pflichtig' => 'Ist Ahv Pflichtig',
            'sprecher_id' => 'Sprecher ID',
            'korrespondenz_lang_code' => 'Korrespondenz lang_code',
            'tel' => 'Mobile 1',
            'tel2' => 'Mobile 2',
            'tel3' => 'Fixnet',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'strasse' => 'Strasse',
            'plz_org' => 'Plz Ort',
            'firma' => 'Firma',
            'bank' => 'Bank',
            'ist_vps_mitglied' => 'Ist Vps Mitglied',
            'braucht_neue_samples' => 'Braucht neue Samples'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSamples()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sample::className(), ['sprecher_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAusgewaehlteSprechers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AusgewaehlteSprecher::className(), ['sprecher_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAuswahls()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Auswahl::className(), ['id' => 'auswahl_id'])->viaTable('ausgewaehlte_sprecher', ['sprecher_id' => 'id']);
    }



    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {

                $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);

                $sample = new Sample();
                $sample->sprecher_id = $this->id;
                $sample->url = 'uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
                $sample->save();

            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private $_ganzer_name = null;

    public function getGanzer_name() {
        return $this->vorname . " " . $this->nachname;
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getlanguages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(language::className(), ['sprecher_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getlang_coden()
    {
        return $this->hasMany( language::className(), [ 'id' => 'categoryID' ] )
            ->via('PeopleCategoriesAssn');
    }

    public function getAllTel() {
        return
            ( empty($this->tel) == false ?'<span title="mobile 1" class="pre">'.$this->tel.'</span>' . "<br/>" : '').
            ( empty($this->tel2) == false ?'<span title="mobile 2" class="pre">'.$this->tel2.'</span>' . "<br/>" : '').
            ( empty($this->tel3) == false ?'<span title="fixnet" class="pre">'.$this->tel3.'</span>' . "<br/>" : '');


    }


    public function getlanguages_txt() {
        $languages = $this->languages;
        $languages_array = array();
        foreach ($languages as $language) {
            $languages_array[] = $language->lang_code;
        }
        return implode(",", $languages_array);
    }


    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getDialekte()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Dialekt::className(), ['sprecher_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getDialekte_txt() {
        $languages = $this->dialekte;
        $languages_array = array();
        foreach ($languages as $language) {
            $languages_array[] = $language->lang_code;
        }
        return implode(",", $languages_array);
    }


    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getEinsatzbereiche()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Einsatzbereich::className(), ['sprecher_id' => 'id']);
    }



    public function getEinsatzbereiche_txt()
    {
        $languages = $this->einsatzbereiche;
        $languages_array = array();
        foreach ($languages as $language) {
            $languages_array[] = $language->bereich;
        }
        return implode("-", $languages_array);
    }

    public function getNationalitaeten()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Nationalitaet::className(), ['sprecher_id' => 'id']);
    }


    public function getNationalitaeten_txt()
    {

        $languages = $this->nationalitaeten;
        $languages_array = array();
        foreach ($languages as $language) {
            $languages_array[] = $language->code;
        }
        return implode("-", $languages_array);
    }





    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @return SprecherQuery the active query used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        return new SprecherQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}
```

View with the GridView:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use kartik\widgets\Select2;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;
use app\models\Sprecher;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\SprecherSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Sprecher';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

$this->registerJsFile(
    '@web/js/main.js',
    ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]
);
?>

<p>
   <!-- <?= Html::a('Create Sprecher', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>-->
</p>

<?php $listen = \app\models\Auswahl::find()->all(); ?>
<div class="auswahl-form">

    <!--  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


 <?= Html::DropDownList("auswahl", 'titel', ArrayHelper::map($listen, 'id', 'titel'),array('prompt'=>'Liste auswählen:', 'options'=>array((isset($auswahl->id) ? $auswahl->id: 0) => array("selected"=>"selected")))) ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>-->

</div>

<?php



?>

<div class="sprecher-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?php

    $data = [
        'Mann' => 'Mann',
        'Frau' => 'Frau',
        'Junge' => 'Junge',
        'Mädchen' => 'Mädchen',
    ];

    $lang_coden = [];
    $query = new yii\db\Query();
    $sprach_codes = $query->select(['lang_code'])
        ->from('languages')
        ->distinct()
        ->all();


    foreach ($sprach_codes as $sprach_code) {
        $lang_coden[$sprach_code["lang_code"]] = $sprach_code["lang_code"];
    }



    $dialekt_codes = $query->select(['lang_code'])
        ->from('dialekt')
        ->distinct()
        ->all();

    $dialekte = [];

    foreach ($dialekt_codes as $dialekt_code) {
        $dialekte[$dialekt_code["lang_code"]] = $dialekt_code["lang_code"];
    }


    $einsatzbereich_codes = $query->select(['bereich'])
        ->from('einsatzbereich')
        ->distinct()
        ->all();

    $einsatzbereiche = [];

    foreach ($einsatzbereich_codes as $einsatzbereich_code) {
        $einsatzbereiche[$einsatzbereich_code["bereich"]] = $einsatzbereich_code["bereich"];
    }


    $nation_codes = $query->select(['code'])
        ->from('nationalitaet')
        ->distinct()
        ->all();

    $nationen = [];

    foreach ($nation_codes as $nation_code) {
        $nationen[$nation_code["code"]] = $nation_code["code"];
    }







    // Generate a bootstrap responsive striped table with row highlighted on hover
    echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,

        'pjax'=>true,

        'toolbar'=> [

            ['content'=>

                Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>', ['create'], ['data-pjax'=>0,'title'=>'Sprecher erfassen', 'class'=>'btn btn-default', 'title'=>'Reset Grid']).
                Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>', ['index'], ['data-pjax'=>0, 'class'=>'btn btn-default', 'title'=>'Reset Grid'])

            ],
            '{export}',
            '{toggleData}',

        ],
        'panel'=>[
            'type'=>GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
            'heading' => $this->title,

        ],
        'toggleDataOptions' =>
            [
                'all' => [
                    'icon' => 'resize-full',
                    'label' => 'Alle',
                    'class' => 'btn btn-default',
                    'title' => 'Zeige alle Datensätze'
                ],
                'page' => [
                    'icon' => 'resize-small',
                    'label' => 'Seiten',
                    'class' => 'btn btn-default',
                    'title' => 'Zeige erste Datenseite'
                ],
            ],
   'columns' => [
       [
           'class' => '\kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'
       ],

       'vorname',
       'nachname',
       [
           'attribute' => 'gender',
           'filter' => $data,
           'filterType' => '\kartik\widgets\Select2',
           'filterWidgetOptions' => [
               'data' => $data,
               'hideSearch'=>true,
               'pluginOptions' => [
                   'allowClear' => true
               ],
               'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Wähle ...', 'multiple' => true, 'hideSearch'=>true,'allowClear' => true,],
           ]


       ],
       [
           'attribute' => 'nationalitaeten',
           'label' => 'Nat.',
           'filter' => $lang_coden,
           'filterType' => '\kartik\widgets\Select2',
           'filterWidgetOptions' => [
               'data' => $nationen,
               'hideSearch'=>true,
               'pluginOptions' => [
                   'allowClear' => true
               ],
               'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Wähle ...', 'multiple' => true, 'hideSearch'=>true,'allowClear' => true,],
           ],
           'value' => 'nationalitaeten_txt'

       ],

       [
           'attribute' => 'dialekte',
           'filter' => $dialekte,
           'filterType' => '\kartik\widgets\Select2',
           'filterWidgetOptions' => [
               'data' => $dialekte,
               'hideSearch'=>true,
               'pluginOptions' => [
                   'allowClear' => true
               ],
               'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Wähle ...', 'multiple' => true, 'hideSearch'=>true,'allowClear' => true,],
           ],
           'value' => 'dialekte_txt'
       ]
       ,
       [
           'attribute' => 'einsatzbereiche',
           'label' => 'Bereich',
           'filter' => $einsatzbereiche,
           'filterType' => '\kartik\widgets\Select2',
           'filterWidgetOptions' => [
               'data' => $einsatzbereiche,
               'hideSearch'=>true,
               'pluginOptions' => [
                   'allowClear' => true
               ],
               'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Wähle ...', 'multiple' => true, 'hideSearch'=>true,'allowClear' => true,],
           ],
           'value' => 'einsatzbereiche_txt'
       ]
       ,
       [
           'attribute' => 'stimmalter',

           'filter' => array("0-20"=>"0-20","20-40"=>"20-40","40-60"=>"40-60","60-80"=>"60-80"),
           'filterType' => '\kartik\widgets\Select2',
           'filterWidgetOptions' => [
               'data' => array("0-20"=>"0-20","20-40"=>"20-40","40-60"=>"40-60","60-80"=>"60-80"),
               'hideSearch'=>true,
               'pluginOptions' => [
                   'allowClear' => true
               ],
               'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Wähle ...', 'multiple' => true, 'hideSearch'=>true,'allowClear' => true,],
           ]


       ],
       [
           'attribute' => 'stimmlage',
           'filter' => array("hoch"=>"hoch","mittel"=>"mittel","tief"=>"tief"),
           'filterType' => '\kartik\widgets\Select2',
           'filterWidgetOptions' => [
               'data' => array("hoch"=>"hoch","mittel"=>"mittel","tief"=>"tief"),
               'hideSearch'=>true,
               'pluginOptions' => [
                   'allowClear' => true
               ],
               'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Wähle ...', 'multiple' => true, 'hideSearch'=>true,'allowClear' => true,],
           ]


       ],
       [
           'attribute' => 'stimmcharakter',
           'label' => 'Charakter',
           'filter' => array("frisch"=>"frisch","hell"=>"hell","neutral"=>"neutral","rauchig"=>"rauchig","seriös"=>"seriös","sonor"=>"sonor"),
           'filterType' => '\kartik\widgets\Select2',
           'filterWidgetOptions' => [
               'data' => array("frisch"=>"frisch","hell"=>"hell","neutral"=>"neutral","rauchig"=>"rauchig","seriös"=>"seriös","sonor"=>"sonor"),
               'hideSearch'=>true,
               'pluginOptions' => [
                   'allowClear' => true
               ],
               'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Wähle ...', 'multiple' => true, 'hideSearch'=>true,'allowClear' => true,],
           ]


       ],
       [
           'class' => '\kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',
           'attribute' => 'ist_schauspieler',
           'label' => 'Actor',
           'trueLabel' => 'Yes',
           'falseLabel' => 'No'
       ],

       [
           'class' => '\kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',
           'attribute' => 'hat_erfahrung_synchron',
           'label' => 'Sync',
           'trueLabel' => 'Yes',
           'falseLabel' => 'No',


       ],

       'bemerkungen',


       [
           'attribute' => 'Samples',
           'format' => 'raw',
           'value' => function ($model) {
               $samples = $model->samples;
               return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_samples', [ 'samples' => $samples]);
           },
       ],
       [
           'attribute' => 'allTel',
           'label' => 'Tel',
           'format' => 'html',
           'value' => 'allTel'
       ],
       [
           'class' => '\kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',
           'attribute' => 'braucht_neue_samples',
           'label' => 'ToDo',
           'trueLabel' => 'Yes',
           'falseLabel' => 'No',


       ],


       [
           'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
           'buttons' => []
       ]

   ],
    'responsive'=>true,
    'hover'=>true,
        'resizableColumns'=>true,
        'resizeStorageKey'=>Yii::$app->user->id . '-' . date("m"),
    ]);
?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

   /* $( document ).ready(function() {
        var files = [document.getElementById("dragout")],
            fileDetails = [];

        // Some forward thinking, utilise the custom data attribute to extend attributes available.
        if(typeof files[0].dataset === "undefined") {
            // Grab it the old way
            fileDetails[0] = files[0].getAttribute("data-downloadurl");

        } else {
            fileDetails[0] = files[0].dataset.downloadurl;

        }

        files[0].addEventListener("dragstart",function(evt){
            evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL",fileDetails[0]);
        },false);

    });
*/

</script>
```

Comment: Post full ModelSearch & Model code (including for the relation) and the view where your Gridview is please, it is not clear what the problem could be from what you have posted. Have you checked in console for pjax errors?

Comment: you havet added how you are comparing the `gender` field are you using `andFilterWhere` or `andWhere` for the comparison.

Comment: @ajmedway - I added the requested source files.